# Unfortunately, App Name has stopped, Logcat.

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook, cordova

I have a problem running my simulator in eclipse. I have fixed my errors (that involved importing the cordova library and connecting my facebook sdk) and I still have some warnings but have run the simulator regardless. It will not let me run the app and crashes when I open it but in my logcat I do not see any actual errors.

Is there a way I can find out what is specifically causing this crash? Help would be great, thank you.

[image]

```
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.764   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.764   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.764   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.764   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.764   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.764   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.764   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.824   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.824   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.824   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.824   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.824   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.864   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.864   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.864   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.864   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.864   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.874   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.874   383:  427 E/SoundPool ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.874   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.874   383:  427 W/AudioService ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:22.884   383:  394 I/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=cafr.db.medicinefinder/.MedicineFinder} from pid 539
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.014    50:   50 D/gralloc  ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/SurfaceFlinger ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -1004994429
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/SurfaceFlinger ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.034    50:   50 E/libEGL   ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.074   383:  394 W/WindowManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21005
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.284   539:  539 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.504  1210: 1210 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:23.514   383:  667 I/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Start proc cafr.db.medicinefinder for activity cafr.db.medicinefinder/.MedicineFinder: pid=1210 uid=10055 gids={50055, 3003}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.014  1210: 1210 I/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Could not find method com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.activateApp, referenced from method cafr.db.medicinefinder.MedicineFinder.onResume
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.014  1210: 1210 W/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): VFY: unable to resolve static method 479: Lcom/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger;.activateApp (Landroid/content/Context;)V
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.014  1210: 1210 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.134  1210: 1210 I/CordovaLog ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Changing log level to  DEBUG(3)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.134  1210: 1210 D/Whitelist ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unlimited access to network resources
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.144  1210: 1210 D/CordovaActivity ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.454  1210: 1210 V/WebViewChromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b1d89db0}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.454  1210: 1210 I/chromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.514  1210: 1210 I/BrowserProcessMain ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.604  1210: 1210 E/chromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.604  1210: 1210 E/chromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.604  1210: 1210 E/chromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.614  1210: 1210 E/chromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.614  1210: 1210 E/chromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.684  1210: 1229 W/chromium ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system  implementation
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.724  1210: 1210 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 5% free 3042K/3188K, paused 48ms, total 49ms
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.724  1210: 1210 I/dalvikvm-heap ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.106MB for 1127536-byte allocation
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.814  1210: 1224 D/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4143K/4292K, paused 51ms, total 51ms
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.884  1210: 1210 D/CordovaWebView ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.894  1210: 1210 D/JsMessageQueue ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Set native->JS mode to 2
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.904  1210: 1210 D/CordovaActivity ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): CordovaActivity.init()
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.924  1210: 1210 D/CordovaWebView ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.924  1210: 1210 D/PluginManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): init()
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:24.944  1210: 1210 D/CordovaWebView ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): >>> loadUrlNow()
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.174  1210: 1210 I/CordovaLog ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Changing log level to   DEBUG(3)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.174  1210: 1210 D/Whitelist ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Unlimited access to network resources
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.184  1210: 1210 D/CordovaActivity ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Resuming the App
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.184  1210: 1210 D/CordovaActivity ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): CB-3064: The errorUrl is     null
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.184  1210: 1210 D/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Shutting down VM
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.184  1210: 1210 W/dalvikvm ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ab3ba8)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.204  1210: 1210 E/AndroidRuntime ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Process: cafr.db.medicinefinder, PID: 1210
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at cafr.db.medicinefinder.MedicineFinder.onResume(MedicineFinder.java:66)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.214   383:  554 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):   Force finishing activity cafr.db.medicinefinder/.MedicineFinder
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.534   383:  554 I/WindowManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b2155880 ActivityRecord{b20b7060 u0 cafr.db.medicinefinder/.MedicineFinder t5 f}} appWin=Window{b20d9018 u0 Starting cafr.db.medicinefinder} drawState=4
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:25.534   383:  554 W/WindowManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (720x1280) to layer 21010
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:26.034   383:  398 W/ActivityManager ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b20b7060 u0 cafr.db.medicinefinder/.MedicineFinder t5 f}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 06-08 11:22:28.284   383:  397 I/Choreographer ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: did you tried restarting eclipse and then running the project on simulator ?

Comment: How do I view my logcat output? @r7v It only says Device Disconnected. And yes, I have tried restarting eclipse but I still get the crash.

Comment: try "adb logcat" from terminal , see if that works .

Comment: @r7v i ran the terminal on mac and put in "adb logcat" and it ran some xcodebuild. I'm in eclipse right now and I restarted the simulator but still nothing shows in logcat. Is there another option?

Comment: @r7v finally spit out some output, i added the logcat in the original post.

Comment: There IS a clear error in your Logcat: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger  (you don't have the FB code available on your simulator, or included in your APK).

Comment: WTF are you talking about Xcode?  Also this is an emulator (not a simulator)

Comment: @Booger can you explain more in-depth of not having the facebook code? http://i.imgur.com/rWgWtVD.png this is my current project -- i thought i imported it correctly but i guess not. and about the xcodebuild, no idea. i ran whatever r7v said in my mac terminal and it ran "xcodebuild" in the taskbar for a second.

Comment: whats the xcodebuild ? seems you are using the facebook sdk and its not able to find the activity , how are you applying the facebook sdk dependecy to your project ? post your gradle file

Comment: @r7v must be a glitch with my mac terminal, thought it was of interest but guess not. here is my facebook gradle: http://textuploader.com/vdgu. my main project does not have a gradle file, seen here: http://i.imgur.com/eTFfIB1.png

Comment: you have posted the build file of the facebook library. what are you using on you main app module ? are you using ant ?

Comment: @r7v phonegap/cordova, built using css/html/php and then importing my project into eclipse.